# phone media query conflict

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using these media queries in my external css:

```
/* Wide Mobile Layout: 480px.
   Gutters: 24px.
   Outer margins: 22px.
   Inherits styles from: Default Layout, Mobile Layout. */

@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px) 

/* Mobile Layout: 320px.
   Gutters: 24px.
   Outer margins: 34px.
   Inherits styles from: Default Layout.
   ---------------------------------------------
   cols    1     2      3 px      68    160    252    */

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

when i'd change max-width: 767px the media query with (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 767px)  width change too would you help me to solve this problem

Comment: it's because the max-width is same in both media queries

Comment: @ Dipaks I guess that but when I'd change max-width to 479 min-width 480 and max width 767 not worked

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the "C" in CSS (Cascading).

Above you're specifying rules for in-between 480px --> 767px, but then below it you're specifying rules for anything below 767px.

Anything in your second media query will override attributes specified in your first media query *with the exception of* if the screen is below 480px.